# Python: "1-2-3-4" to [1, 2, 3, 4]

Tags: python

What is the best way to convert a string on the format `"1-2-3-4"` to a list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`? The string may also be empty, in which case the conversion should return an empty list `[]`.

This is what I have:

```
map(lambda x: int(x),
    filter(lambda x: x != '',
           "1-2-3-4".split('-')))
```

EDIT: Sorry all of those who answered before I corrected my question, it was unclear for the first minute or so.

Comment: you realise that you're not checking for empty string, right? you're checking whether new list's item is an empty string. these are different things.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I do realize that my algorithm could be made differently, but my approach works as well. `"".split("-")` returns `[""]`. The asymptotic time complexity of my algorithm is worse than ideal, but it is negligible in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to make it shorter. Use the `if` to account for the empty string.

```
the_string = '1-2-3-4'

[int(x) for x in the_string.split('-') if x != '']
```

Comment: why are you checking for empty string like this?

Comment: SilentGhost, the question says that in the case of an empty string it should return an empty list: "The string may also be empty, in which case the conversion should return an empty list []."

Comment: so why do you do it the way you do it? you're not aware of what object evaluate to False?

Comment: `>>> [x for x in ''.split('-')]`\n 
`['']`\n 
`>>> [x for x in '-'.split('-')]`\n 
`['', '']`

Comment: `>>> [int(x) for x in ''.split('-') if x != '']` \n 
`[]`

Comment: `>>> [int(i) for i in ''.split('-') if i]`

Comment: Good point. The != '' part is pointless. +1 to your comment. But still, it might be good for clarity.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> for s in ["", "0", "-0-0", "1-2-3-4"]:
...     print(map(int, filter(None, s.split('-'))))
... 
[]
[0]
[0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This won't adress the empty sting case.

Comment: @voyager: I just updated the answer to fix that. (Hope you're OK with that, Nadia.)

Comment: `filter(bool, ..)` or `filter(len, ..)` might be easier to read than `filter(None, ..)`.

Answer (score 4):

Convert the higher-order functions to a more readable list-comprehension

```
[ int(n) for n in "1-2-3-4".split('-') if n != '' ]
```

The rest is fine.

Answer (score 2):

From the format of your example, you want int's in the list.  If so, then you will need to convert the string numbers to int's.  If not, then you are done after the string split.

```
text="1-2-3-4"

numlist=[int(ith) for ith in text.split('-')]
print numlist
[1, 2, 3, 4]

textlist=text.split('-')
print textlist
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

EDIT:  Revising my answer to reflect the update in the question.

If the list can be malformed then "try...catch" if your friend.  This will enforce that the list is either well formed, or you get an empty list.

```
>>> def convert(input):
...     try:
...         templist=[int(ith) for ith in input.split('-')]
...     except:
...         templist=[]
...     return templist
...     
>>> convert('1-2-3-4')
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> convert('')
[]
>>> convert('----1-2--3--4---')
[]
>>> convert('Explicit is better than implicit.')
[]
>>> convert('1-1 = 0')
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this:

```
>>> the_string = '1-2-3-4- -5-   6-'
>>>
>>> [int(x.strip()) for x in the_string.split('-') if len(x)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(s):
    if s:
        return map(int, s.split("-"))
    else:
        return []
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the lambda, and split won't give you empty elements:

```
map(int, filter(None,x.split("-")))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that breaks on empty strings.

Comment: hmmm... I didn't noticed that split would return an empty string if the input was an empty string (I thought it returned an empty list). Fixed with a filter